# How to handle a list of custom datatype in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I know that I can operate with lists in haskell like tihs:

```
    quicksort :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]  
    quicksort [] = []  
    quicksort (x:xs) =   
        let smallerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a <= x]  
            biggerSorted = quicksort [a | a <- xs, a > x]  
        in  smallerSorted ++ [x] ++ biggerSorted
```

But what if I have a custom data class `human`?

```
data Human = Human String Int
```

I tried

```
areAllAdults :: [Human] -> Bool
areAllAdults (Human name age):xs=age>21&&areAllAdults xs
...
```

But I get an error. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please include your full function, rather than eliding part of it with `...`. Likewise include the actual error. Error messages are there specifically to diagnose problems. If you throw them away and ask "what problem am I having?", you are making things harder for no reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were quite close, you can recurse with:

```
areAllAdults :: [Human] -> Bool
areAllAdults (Human name age : xs) = age > 21 && areAllAdults x
areAllAdults [] = True
```

But it makes more sense to work with `all`:

```
areAllAdults :: [Human] -> Bool
areAllAdults = all (\(Human _ age) -> age > 21)
```